# Getting blue screen error while I am working

Tags: display, windows-error-reporting, memory-error, bluescreenview

I am using a Lenovo system. It has been working very well for me but now I have started getting a blue screen error. I am not sure why I am getting this error. I ignored it a couple of times but I am worried about this error now because I lose my work.

Comment: I also cleaned my https://www.allhdd.com/hpe-p00924-b21-memory/ memory and it didn't work. How can I troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: You need to use a tool like BlueScreenView (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to get the debug information which you can then post here

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)